# prolog counting occurrences knowledge base

Tags: count, prolog

```
% Knowledgebase

parents (pedro, jose).
parents (pedro, john).
parents (pedro, mary).    
parent (john, leidis).    
parent (john, marten).    
parents (leidis, berta).    
parents (berta, pepe).
```

It has a knowledge base as above in which parents interact and
children (the first element is the father and the second son), is to develop a
preached that because a parent has returned many children.
the answer to the following questions to the base of previous knowledge would be:

```
? - Cant_hijos (pedro, Cant).
Qty = 3

? - Cant_hijos (john, Cant).
Qty = 2

? - Cant_hijos (leidis, Cant).
Qty = 1
```

Comment: Remove the spaces between `parent` and `(`, also `parents -> parent`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cant_hijos(P, N) :-
   setof(C, parent(P,C), Cs),
   length(Cs, N).
```

Note that it fails for zero many children. It would not make sense to ask:

```
?- cant_hijos(P, 0).
```

As there are infinitely many names that are not parents.